# What does ていた mean?

Tags: syntax, tense, aspect

I could not understand ていた right after 晴れ in the sentence below.

> 海岸に行った時、とてもよく晴れ**ていた**んです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ていた doesn't mean anything on itself, because it's a part of conjugation:

- 晴れる{はれる} - the verb - which means roughly "to become clear" (as in clear weather).
- 晴れて{はれて} - verb's te-form
- て+いる - a grammar form for continuous action
- て+いた - continuous action in the past

Combined, 晴れていた means "it was sunny" or "the skies were clear".

Comment: It's a nitpicking but I'd say 晴れる is to "become" clear.

Comment: @brokenheadphones It was actually an edit not from me. Feel free to correct it.